# Routes are not deleted while deleting the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

When I deleted a controller I noticed that the corresponding routes are not deleted from the `routes.rb` file. Is there any reason for rails not to delete it?

Comment: How are you deleting the controller?

Comment: @Pavan: created by rails g controller Posts name:string user:references , destroyed by rails d controller Posts.

Comment: Try `rails d scaffold Posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routes` which belong to that controller ***won't be deleted*** when you give  `rails d controller Posts` since they are not created when the command `rails g controller Posts name:string user:references` is run. The contents which are generated by `rails g controller Posts name:string user:references` are only deleted when you give `rails d controller Posts`

For example, the command `rails g controller nurseries` creates the below files

```
  create  app/controllers/nurseries_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/nurseries
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/controllers/nurseries_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/nurseries_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/helpers/nurseries_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/nurseries.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/nurseries.css.scss
```

Now when you give `rails destroy controller nurseries` the content which is created with the command is only deleted

```
  remove  app/controllers/nurseries_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  remove    app/views/nurseries
  invoke  test_unit
  remove    test/controllers/nurseries_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  remove    app/helpers/nurseries_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/helpers/nurseries_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  remove      app/assets/javascripts/nurseries.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  remove      app/assets/stylesheets/nurseries.css.scss
```

May be you should ***manually erase*** the `routes` or if you are generated the controller with help of ***scaffold*** i.e, `rails g scaffold Posts name:string user:references` then giving `rails d scaffold Posts` will do it for you, but it also deletes all the other content(model,migration files etc) along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not edit your files unless you call a command to do so (i.e. `rails generate ...`)

So when you delete a file from your hard disk with `rm app/controller/foos_controller.rb` there is no process which could edit your `routes.rb` file.